# In selenium with java need reusable method to verify isElement present which may have different locators like xpath, id, class name

Tags: java, selenium

I want to write a reusable method to identify whether the web Element is Present or not.
This method needs to accept e different locators like xpath, id, class name.

Here is the code snipped I tried, but not worked for the line.
if(Obj.isDisplayed())

```
public static boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, WebElement Obj)
{
    boolean result = false;
    try 
    {
        // if(Obj.isDisplayed())
        if(driver.findElement(By.id("username")) != null)
        {
            System.out.println("WEBELEMENT Username FOUND");
            result = true;
        }
        else
        {
            result = false;
        }
    }   
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below method returns true in case element present.

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebDriver driver,By locator){

    if(driver.findElements(locator).size()!=0){
        //Element present
        return true;

    }
    else{
        //Element not present 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Example:

```
   isElementPresent(By.id("test"));

   isElementPresent(By.xpath("//test1"));
```

For your case solution will be Try/Catch:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(WebElement element) {
   try {
       element.getText();
       return true;
      } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
       return false;
      }
```

If element not exists on the page then element.getText() will throw NosuchElementException, method will catch this exception and returns false.

Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: here, for the "By Locator"  what value we have to provide while calling this method. Also I have all the WebElements stored in a class file like this       @FindBy(id = "username")
     public static WebElement Username;
 
 @FindBy(id = "password")
 public static WebElement Password;
 
 @FindBy (xpath = "//img[contains(@src, 'logo-icon-big.png')]")
 public static WebElement Logo;

Comment: Updated solution with Try/catch, try it.

Comment: Thanks Akarsh for your timely response. I already tried with the try catch block, hence not tried your last approach. It is a small part of Bigger Automation framework. It goes like this: IsElementPresent () will be used by enterText () and then Click (). So this isElementPresent() should be reusable by many test cases, hence i want it in a way no hard code value in the method.

Comment: I think my last solution don't have any hard codes right?

Comment: Hi Akarsh, element.getText(); throws Null pointer exception, though the web element is displayed. Also for the same web element i tried driver.findElement method which works fine.     if(driver.findElements(Locator).size()!=0 ){
   System.out.println("WebElement found");
   return true;